# Laravel 8 call other model relationship in model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

[image]

I have that relationship, and the main problem is how do I show Product where has relationship with product_image / discounts and render that on the blade?

There my Cart class model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id','id');
}
```

There's my product class model :

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function getProductImage()
{
    return $this->images->image_name;
}
```

This is both what`discount` and `product_images` code to returning relationship

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id','id');
}
```

And how do I show that on my Cart blade? I've use this but still shows error

```
@foreach($cart as $data)
    @foreach ($data->products as $item)
        <th scope="row">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image->image ) }}"class="border" style="width:120px;" alt="">
        </th>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: WHAT IS THE ERROR????

Comment: im just trying to show product_images on cart view using relationship on product model and still can't find how to show that

Comment: please share what is `@dd('$cart')` is showing......... also what is `@dd('$data')` and `@dd('$data->products')` are showing

Comment: sorry bro , already answered with this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897935/render-has-many-relationship-with-eager-loading-data-in-blade-using-compact-gets

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get a single value directly from multiple relations.

```
public function getProductImage()
{
    return $this->images->image_name;
}
```

You are trying to directly print the image of more than one image.

```
@foreach($cart as $data)
    @foreach ($data->products as $item)
        <th scope="row">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->image->image ) }}"class="border" style="width:120px;" alt="">
        </th>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**It could be like this.**

You determine the first image of the product as the main image.

Product Model:

```
.....
    protected $appends = ["mainImage"];
.....
public function getMainImageAttribute()
    {
        return $this->images()->first()->image_name;
    }
```

Thus, you can capture the image with the attribute you have defined from within the product.

```
@foreach($cart as $data)
    @foreach ($data->products as $item)
        <th scope="row">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$item->mainImage ) }}"class="border" style="width:120px;" alt="">
        </th>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: it's already solved by another topic that i found on stackoverflow , but thanks for advice, maybe sometime it's may help me on future^^